# sed find and replace fastq regex

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a file such as

```
head testSed.fastq
@M01551:51:000000000-BCB7H:1:1101:15800:1330 1:N:0:NGTCACTN+TATCCTCTCTTGAAGA
NGTCACTN
+
#>AAAAF#
@M01551:51:000000000-BCB7H:1:1101:15605:1331 1:N:0:NATCAGCN+TAGATCGCCAAGTTAA
NATCAGCN
+
#>>AA?C#
@M01551:51:000000000-BCB7H:1:1101:15557:1332 1:N:0:NCAGCAGN+TATCTTCTATAAATAT
NCAGCAGN
```

And I am attempting to replace the string after the final colon with `0` (in this example on lines 1,5,9 - but globally) using a regular expression.

I have checked my regex using egrep `egrep '[ATGCN]{8}\+[ATGCN]{16}$' testSed.fastq` which returns all the lines I would expect.

However when I try to use `sed -i 's/[ATGCN]{8}\+[ATGCN]{16}$/0/g' testSed.fastq` the original file is unchanged and no replacement occurs.

How can I fix this? Is my regex not specific enough?

Comment: you need to escape `{}` or use `-E/-r`

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: @skurp, user 123 is suggesting `sed -E -i ...` to enable egrep-style extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is structured as an ERE rather than a BRE, which is sed's default interpretation. Not all sed implementations support ERE, but you can check `man sed` in your environment to determine whether it's possible for you. Look for `-r` or `-E` options. You can alternately use bounds  by preceding the curly braces with backslashes.

That said, rather than matching the precise text in the last field, why not just look for the string that starts with a colon, and is followed by no-more-colons?  The following RE is both BRE and ERE compatible.

```
$ sed '/^@/s/:[^:]*$/:0/' testq
@M01551:51:000000000-BCB7H:1:1101:15800:1330 1:N:0:0
NGTCACTN
+
#>AAAAF#
@M01551:51:000000000-BCB7H:1:1101:15605:1331 1:N:0:0
NATCAGCN
+
#>>AA?C#
@M01551:51:000000000-BCB7H:1:1101:15557:1332 1:N:0:0
NCAGCAGN
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need a regex for this?

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: '/^@/ {$NF = "0"} 1' testfile
```

That won't save in-place. If you have GNU awk you can

```
gawk -F: -v OFS=: -i inplace '...' file
```

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html

Comment: Note `-i inplace` is only 4.0+